# Java Run Command pipe on linux

Tags: java, linux, command, pipe

I am trying to get output of piped command in linux environment but so far no luck.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh",  "-c", "top", "-b", "-n", "2", "-d", "0.2", "-p", pid + "", "|",  "tail",  "-1", "|", "awk", "'{print $6}'");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
p.getOutputStream().close();
try (InputStream is = p.getInputStream()) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

This outputs: `top: failed tty get`

When I try that without specifying the script executor (/bin/bash -c): `top: unknown option '|'`

Comment: Haven’t used process builder, so I can’t speak to what all those flags are doing. But that’s some complicated stuff. I’m pretty confident the error about failing tty get is because you’re trying to run an interactive  program (top) in a non-interactive way.  Top wants to grab the tty so it can paint the whole screen.  You’re running it in a way where it can’t paint the screen.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The shell command should be a single argument passed after `-c`. The invoked shell will take care of the piping and tokenization:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c",
     "top -b -n 2 -d 0.2 -p " + pid + " | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'");
```

For robustness bonus points, pass the variables as separate arguments instead of injecting them into the string (like how you'd use prepared statements in SQL):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c",
     "top -b -n 2 -d 0.2 -p \"$1\" | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'", "_", String.valueOf(pid));
```

It makes no difference when `pid` is an integer, but if it's an arbitrary string, this improves security and robustness.